# Eevee get darker shadows

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

I've setup a scene just the way I like it (world surface lighting and two directional lights) but shadows are not dark enough.

Decreasing world color and compensating it with increased lights color looks worse.

What should I try?

Using Blender 2.90.1 and Eevee

Here is the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1elA_yihyFeN1jwiWnPg2coCEW14NLecZ/view

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it looks worse in what way?

Comment: @moonboots less vivid and darker in general. I want to have overall look like on the first image and shadows like on the second image.

Comment: to keep sharp shadows you need to keep the light Angle value low. Also =, to have more control make sure that the world is black. You can also give negative values to lights to make a part darker if you ever need...

Comment: @moonboots I'm okay with shadows not being sharp, it's the color that matters to me. And If I make the world completely black how can I get back that nice vivid ambient look? Tried setting light strength to a negative value - looks weird, shadows now appear brighter than everything else, not darker (which they are supposed to be).

Comment: it's all a question of light settings, what does it give if you increase your sun strength? 1 is a pretty low value

Comment: actually I don't see any reason why you couldn't have the same colors as picture 1, maybe share a part of your file so that we can test?

Comment: @moonboots sure, here it is
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1elA_yihyFeN1jwiWnPg2coCEW14NLecZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks but you should pack the images before sharing: File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend. Have you tried to increase your sun strength?

Comment: @moonboots Sorry about that, I've updated the link. Yes, I've tried increasing sun strength, but it makes everything too bright for my taste.

Comment: I can't see the new link, please put it in your initial question

Comment: @moonboots got it

Comment: Have you tried negative light?
https://youtu.be/55OM0acVwdE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't open your link, but in general in Eevee you can use *Shader to RGB*, then separate the Value in order to do something with it (e.g. increase contrast). I decided to use a color ramp, divided the range and repeated the division a few times for the darkest values to only affect shadows.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So here is a quick try: First, deactivate the world in the *Shader Editor*, increase a bit the strength of the 2 suns to 2, as the shadows are a bit too dark and as you need to compensate a bit the removal of the world, create a point light in the middle of your room, disable its shadow option and give it a strength of 300 W. It may need a bit of tweakings but I think I'm not far from what you want?

Edit: also, maybe a *Light Probe > Irradiance Volume* will improve the lighting, to be tested

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid a point light doesn't look quite good fore me. I ended up balancing existing directional lights and a world color to get a decent look. I don't think I should post it as an accepted answer since it doesn't solve the initial question. Thanks for your advices though!

Comment: no problem, actually it was just a question of light settings, and yes I guess it needs time, especially in Eevee